# How to require in jQuery code that exists within a ruby gem in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I found online resources for how to add `jQuery` *itself* into a rails 6 app, but I was having trouble finding out how to require in the jquery code that exists inside of a *rubygems.org gem*.

I am trying to require in the jQuery code from the [nested_form_fields gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/nested_form_fields).

### Here is how I did it in Rails 5:

1. Add the gem within the `Gemfile`:

   ```
   gem 'nested_form_fields
   ```
2. Run `bundle install` to install the gem:
3. Add the following line within `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` to require in jquery code from the third party gem:

   ```
   //= require nested_form_fields
   ```

And that is it.

---

### Here is how I attempted to do it in Rails 6:

1. Add the following line into `app/javascript/packs/application.js` to load in jquery:

   ```
   require("jquery")
   ```
2. Add the gem within the `Gemfile`:

   ```
   gem 'nested_form_fields'
   ```
3. Run `bundle install` to install the gem:
4. Add the following line within `app/javascript/packs/application.js` to bring in the javascript code which exists inside the `nested_form_fields` gem:

   ```
   require("nested_form_fields")
   ```

When I boot up my app and look at web inspector it says the following:

> Error: Cannot find module 'nested_form_fields'

I didn't expect it to work via `yarn` either because `nested_form_fields` isn't a package within yarn.  Instead: I'm simply trying to require in the javascript code that happens to exist *inside* of a ruby gem. But for good measure I attempted it anyways just to rule that out:

```
yarn add nested_form_fields
...
=> error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/nested_form_fields: Not found".
```

I know this is going to be one of those things where I forgot to do something simple, but I've been at this for a while and another pair of eyes might be able to catch it quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design of `Rails 6` is steering developers away from the `asset pipeline` and towards `webpack`. It appears that this means gems used in rails, which contain javascript, will likely need to be updated.

- Specifically: instead of hardcoding the javascript into the ruby gem, the ruby gem would only reference the dependent javascript. That dependent javascript would exist separately in  the `npm` repository. I'm no expert, but I believe this is the idea.

My solution was to swap out [nested_form_fields](https://rubygems.org/gems/nested_form_fields) for [cocoon](https://rubygems.org/gems/cocoon) which essentially provides the same nested-form-handling behavior.

The funny thing is that `cocoon` is in the exact same predicament as `nested_form_fields`. However, `cocoon` is more popular and likewise has more community looking for the best way to solve this puzzle. [Issue #555](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/555) captures this particular problem.

I eventually decided to implement the temporary work around [described in this comment](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/555#issuecomment-530192116). Essentially what I did was I copy/pasted the jQuery code from the `cocoon` gem into my rails app, and then I required that code into `webpack`.

#### Steps to get Cocoon Up and Running in Rails 6

1. Add cocoon to the `Gemfile`

   ```
   gem "cocoon"
   ```
2. Run `bundle install` to install the gem.
3. Copy/paste the `cocoon` [javascript code located here](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/cocoon.js) into a new file at: `app/javascript/src/cocoon.js`
4. Add the following two lines into `javascript/packs/application.js`.  Cocoon depends on jquery so we need to require that in, and then of course require in the cocoon javascript that we copy/pasted in step #3:

   ```
   require("jquery")
   require("src/cocoon.js")
   ```

That is the best temporary strategy that I am aware of.

Comment: Or you could create just create a public or private [yarn package](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/creating-a-package/).